# Need Help to Move a pattern to End Of Line

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've been making auto logcat to sepolicy code with regex on HTML page.

My problem is that i need to move the `{ .* };` to end of line and i couldn't find how to do that.

Some examples:
`allow { read }; recovery rctl_dumpstate_props:file` 
where the `{ read };` needs to go to end of line.

`allow { getattr }; recovery rcgroups:file`
where the `{ getattr };` needs to go to end of line.

I've tried multiple ReGex from other similar problems from other people
like `^(.*)( {.*?};)(.*)$` and replace `\1\3\2` but i get output like this (weird squares):

instead of the code i need.
I need it to be PCRE (PHP). Thanks!

Comment: Normally, you should **capture group** and swap their position. [https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups). Look [https://regex101.com/r/idMy0w/3](https://regex101.com/r/idMy0w/3)

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: I've tried search: ((\w+)_(\w+)) replace: \3, \2, \1 and browsed all over stackoverflow but none answers worked

Comment: What language/tool are you using? And [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58147079/372239) to show us what you have tried, with strings before **and** after replace.

Comment: alright i will edit

Comment: Valijon's answer worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are not using properly `preg_replace`. Have a try with:

```
$texts = ['allow { read }; recovery rctl_dumpstate_props:file',
          'allow { getattr }; recovery rcgroups:file'];
foreach ($texts as $str) {
    echo preg_replace('/^(.+?)( { .+? };)(.+)$/', '$1$3$2', $str),"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
allow recovery rctl_dumpstate_props:file { read }; 
allow recovery rcgroups:file { getattr };
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with Python3 [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), which uses Perl regex syntax.

```py
import re
>>> re.sub('^(.*)( {.*?};)(.*)$', r'\1\3\2', 'allow { read }; recovery rctl_dumpstate_props:file')
'allow recovery rctl_dumpstate_props:file { read };'
```

You will probably need to make adjustments for whitespace, but the gist of it is that you capture 3 groups (the prefix, the text between curly braces, and the suffix; and then you swap their positions.

Comment: i need to do it in html ;_;

Comment: Do you mean javascript?

Comment: no. php base code is logcat = logcat.replace(/regex/gmi, "replace with");

Comment: `logcat = logcat.replace(/regex/gmi, "replace with");` does not look like PHP. When asking a regex-related question, you are supposed to add an additional tag that is the language being used.